# How to run golang-migrate with docker-compose?

Tags: database, docker, go, migration

In golang-migrate's documentation, it is stated that you can run this command to run all the migrations in one folder.

```
docker run -v {{ migration dir }}:/migrations --network host migrate/migrate
    -path=/migrations/ -database postgres://localhost:5432/database up 2
```

How would you do this to fit the syntax of the new docker-compose, which discourages the use of `--network`?

And more importantly: How would you connect to a database in another container instead to one running in your localhost?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Adding this to your `docker-compose.yml` will do the trick:

```
    db:
        image: postgres
        networks:
            new:
                aliases:
                    - database
        environment:
            POSTGRES_DB: mydbname
            POSTGRES_USER: mydbuser
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mydbpwd
        ports:
            - "5432"
    migrate:
        image: migrate/migrate
        networks:
            - new
        volumes:
            - .:/migrations
        command: ["-path", "/migrations", "-database",  "postgres://mydbuser:mydbpwd@database:5432/mydbname?sslmode=disable", "up", "3"]
        links: 
            - db
networks:
      new:
```

Instead of using the `--network host` option of `docker run` you set up a network called `new`. All the services inside that network gain access to each other through a defined alias (in the above example, you can access the db service through the `database` alias). Then, you can use that alias just like you would use `localhost`, that is, in place of an IP address. That explains this connection string:

```
"postgres://mydbuser:mydbpwd@database:5432/mydbname?sslmode=disable"
```

Comment: Hello, is there a way to add a script to wait until the postgres debase is ready? because, if you run that docker-compose file as it is, you'll get a connection refused the first time you run it. `migrate_1   | error: dial tcp 172.22.0.2:5432: connect: connection refused`

Comment: @tul1 there is. Check here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: it doesn't work because the [migrate/migrate](https://hub.docker.com/layers/migrate/migrate/latest/images/sha256-254d67343a2389383b530d9049610f21f4d302557288c649ebbb761ea96b10af?context=explore) docker from dockerhub runs the command "migrate". It's not posible to inject a command before that?

Comment: I found the answer to my own question and I've published below. :)

Answer (score 6):

As of Compose file formats version 2 you do not have to setup a network.

As stated in the [docker networking documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.

So in you case you could do something like:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
   #note this databaseservice name is what we will use instead
   #of localhost when using migrate as compose assigns
   #the service name as host
   #for example if we had another container in the same compose
   #that wnated to access this service port 2000 we would have written
   # databaseservicename:2000
  databaseservicename:
    image: postgres:13.3-alpine

    restart: always

    ports:
      - "5432"

    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_USER: username
      POSTGRES_DB: database

    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

    #if we had another container that wanted to access migrate container at let say
    #port 1000
    #and it's in the same compose file  we would have written migrate:1000
  migrate:
    image: migrate/migrate

    depends_on:
      - databaseservicename

    volumes:
      - path/to/you/migration/folder/in/local/computer:/database
    # here instead of localhost as the host we use databaseservicename as that is the name we gave to the postgres service
    command:
      [ "-path", "/database", "-database",  "postgres://databaseusername:databasepassword@databaseservicename:5432/database?sslmode=disable", "up" ]
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

Answer (score 6):

The answer provided by @Federico work for me at the beginning, nevertheless, I realised that I've been gotten a `connect: connection refused` the first time the docker-compose was run in brand new environment, but not the second one. This means that the migrate container runs before the Database is ready to process operations. Since, [migrate/migrate](https://hub.docker.com/layers/migrate/migrate/latest/images/sha256-254d67343a2389383b530d9049610f21f4d302557288c649ebbb761ea96b10af?context=explore) from docker-hub runs the "migration" command whenever is ran, it's not possible to add a wait_for_it.sh script to wait for the db to be ready. So we have to add `depends_on` and a `healthcheck` tags to manage the order execution.
So this is my docker file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    networks:
      new:
        aliases:
          - database
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: mydbname
      POSTGRES_USER: mydbuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mydbpwd
    ports:
      - "5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready -U mydbuser -d mydbname
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 5

  migrate:
    image: migrate/migrate
    networks:
      - new
    volumes:
      - .:/migrations
    command: ["-path", "/migrations", "-database",  "postgres://mydbuser:mydbpwd@database:5432/mydbname?sslmode=disable", "up", "3"]
    links: 
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
networks:
      new:
```