# Dockerfile for Go and Postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, migration

I need to make a Docker container with Go-app and Postgres db with migrated tables. All what I could find is combinations of these topics ([1](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/dockerized-crud-restful-api-with-go-gorm-jwt-postgresql-mysql-and-testing-61d731430bd8), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55779979/how-to-run-golang-migrate-with-docker-compose))

Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:alpine as builder
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache git
WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o main .
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=builder /app/main .
COPY --from=builder /app/.env .
EXPOSE 8080
RUN chmod +x ./main
CMD ["./main"]
```

And I've got error `standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error`
I found that this is probably due to incompatibility of systems and architectures (I have Windows nd Intel x64), but none of the decisions helped.
Can you help me with Dockerfile or with my error?

Comment: Are you running this on amd64 CPU?

Comment: I can't see anything in the info provided that explains the error (if I fix your `docker-compose.yml` by removing the link to `db` and add test go code then everything starts on my x64 windows box). Please try with running just your app without compose (i.e. `docker build - t test .` then `docker run -t test`).

Comment: @blami I have Intel x64 CPU

Comment: @Brits it's successfully built, but while running the same error: exec format error

Comment: Ok I'd suggest updating your question and removing references to compose (aiming for [**minimal** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). Please try removing the `GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64` from the dockerfile.

Comment: @Brits same exec format error

Comment: OK - Can you try it with a minimalistic application; try to get to the point where your question contains everything needed to replicate the issue ([this](https://go.dev/play/p/ZCQUSg5s73V) is what I used when testing on my PC).

Comment: @Brits yes, this app works well with docker on my PC

Comment: OK so the issue relates to your application specifically. You will need to do a bit more debugging and significantly update your question (it's clear this has nothing to do with Postgres so we need to know more about the application). Perhaps start a console in the app `docker run -t test /bin/sh` and have a look at `/root/main` or, maybe, step back to a single stage build until you have that bit working.