# In docker container are not created db migrations

Tags: python, docker, go

Can anyone say why my migrations are not created in docker container? Locally I have a working project but in container there are no tables.
Locally my tables are created but when I run docker-compose up there are no migrations in console logs

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.17-alpine as build-stage

RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app
RUN go mod download

RUN go build -o crypto main.go

FROM alpine:latest

WORKDIR /

COPY --from=build-stage /app/crypto .

EXPOSE 9999

ENTRYPOINT [ "/crypto" ]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

volumes:
  crypto_postgres_data: {}

services:
  crypto:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: crypto_app
    platform: linux/amd64
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "9999:9999"

  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.2 
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "$POSTGRES_USER", "-d", "$POSTGRES_DB" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 10s
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - ./.env 
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '1'
          memory: 4G
    volumes:
      - crypto_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z
  migrate:
    image: migrate/migrate
    volumes:
      - .:/migrations
```

```
My output in container:
[gomigrate] 2022/06/22 14:02:11 Migrations path: migrations/
[gomigrate] 2022/06/22 14:02:11 Migrations table not found
[gomigrate] 2022/06/22 14:02:11 Created migrations table: gomigrate
[gomigrate] 2022/06/22 14:02:11 Migrations file pairs found: 0
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The [golang-migrate/migrate GitHub repository page](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate) has a more involved `docker run` command; do you need some of the command-line options like `-path=/migrations -database=postgres://postgres`?

Comment: We don't even know what you're doing with your docker files. Please provide the minimal elements for us to understand what you intent to do and how you try.

Answer (score 0):

Your migrate service does not have any command so it cannot migrate data in the migrations folder. You should change it like this:

```
version: "3"

volumes:
  crypto_postgres_data: {}

services:
  crypto:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: crypto_app
    platform: linux/amd64
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "9999:9999"
    networks:
      - crypto

  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.2 
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "$POSTGRES_USER", "-d", "$POSTGRES_DB" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 10s
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - ./.env 
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '1'
          memory: 4G
    volumes:
      - crypto_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z
    networks:
      - crypto

  migrate:
    image: migrate/migrate
    restart: on-failure:5 
    env_file:
      - ./.env 
    volumes:
      - ./migrations:/migrations
    command: ["-path", "/migrations", "-database",  "postgres://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@postgres:5432/${POSTGRES_DB}?sslmode=disable", "up"]
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - crypto

networks:
  crypto:
    driver: bridge
```

Reference: [How to run golang-migrate with docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55779979/how-to-run-golang-migrate-with-docker-compose)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it's better to use `volume` option where `migrate` `service` in `docker-compose` file.

You can easily create migration files without using so long command like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55779979/how-to-run-golang-migrate-with-docker-compose) also without `docker`.

You can look example [here](https://github.com/Almazatun/lien-court). Also, the project represents how you can run migration files with the `docker-compose` running `postgres` service.